# Python Code to extract values from xml saved in txt file

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get the multiple values from a single line of text file
I have xml code saved in text file as shown below

```
<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>DXB</CityCode><CountryCode>EG</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>TA</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>95HAJSTI</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></ServiceRQ>
```

I have multiple xml lines stored in txt file. How can I extract date from each line and store in excel sheet like

```
Type       Channel     AG
ServiceRQ    TA      95HAJSTI
SearchRQ     AY      56ASJSTS
SearviceRQ   QA      85ATAKSQ
 ...         ..      ....
 ...         ..      ....
```

Data stored in text file is as:

```
<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>DXB</CityCode><CountryCode>EG</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>TA</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>95HAJSTI</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></ServiceRQ>

<SearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>CPT</CityCode><CountryCode>US</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>AY</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>56ASJSTS</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></SearchRQ>

<ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityCode>BOM</CityCode><CountryCode>AU</CountryCode><Currency>USD</Currency><Channel>QA</Channel></SaleInfo><Pricing><CustomParams><Param Name="AG"><Value>85ATAKSQ</Value></Param></CustomParams></Pricing></ServiceRQ>

<ServiceRQ ......

<SearchRQ ........
```

and so on...

I am trying to get the desire output using regex but. Finding it difficult to create the exact regex pattern.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['Data'])
    
df['Type'] = df['Data'].str.extract('<(.*)\s+xmlns')
df['Channel'] = df['Data'].str.extract('<Channel>(.*)</Channel>')
df['AG'] = df['Data'].str.extract('<Param Name="AG"><Value>(.*)</Value>')

print (df)

                                                Data       Type Channel  \
0  <ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><City...  ServiceRQ      TA   
1  <SearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><CityC...   SearchRQ      AY   
2  <ServiceRQ xmlns:xsi="http://"><SaleInfo><City...  ServiceRQ      QA   

         AG  
0  95HAJSTI  
1  56ASJSTS  
2  85ATAKSQ
```

Comment: Hello jezrael, I have xml data stored in txt file not in csv

Comment: @Rejoy - It is not problem, use `df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', names=['Data'])`

Comment: `chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 808, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 866, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 852, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1973, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 16, saw 5`

Comment: @Rejoy can you try `df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', names=['Data'], sep='|')` ?